# Regex to check if all the field is within brackets

Tags: regex, postgresql

I am trying to develop an if statement that will check if all of the text is within brackets. I am doing this within a postgres DB (`plpgsql` function) so I was trying to use regexp_replace and doing a length check but I am struggling.

So far, I have this:

```
if length(regexp_replace((substring(word from '(.+)\(')), '\s+', '', 'g'))>0 then
```

This checks to see if the text in brackets has any words before the brackets, and I have something similar to check if there are words after the brackets.

Is there any way to do this better? Ie, possibly check to see if the entire `word` is within brackets and there is nothing else outside the brackets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this [regexp match](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-TABLE) expression is simpler.
Check if `word` is a bracketed string w/o non-whitespace characters out of the brackets.

```sql
if word ~ '^\s*\(.*\)\s*$' then
-- your code here 
end if;
```

**Edit**
Then try

```sql
if substring(word from '(?:^|[^\(])\m([\w ]+)\M(?:^|[^\)])') is null then
-- your code here 
end if;
```

The `substring` expression shall return the non-bracketed word if any.

Comment: That is so close to what I need, the only issue is if the word looks like this - '(bracket 1) generic (bracket 2)` in which case I would want to return false as not all of the text is in brackets